# Error when installing MultiNest for MPI - missing Fortran libraries

Tags: mpi, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install MultiNest and PyMultiNest on Ubutnu 16.04.  I have OpenMPI installed and can successfully run programs with it. However, during the installation of MultiNest, I get this:

```
kevin@kevin-VirtualBox:~/MultiNest/build$ cmake ..
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Detected gfortran, adding -ffree-line-length-none compiler flag.
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:406 (message):
  Unable to find MPI library mpi_mpifh
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:596 (interrogate_mpi_compiler)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:86 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Could NOT find MPI_Fortran (missing:  MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES) 
-- MPI not found, only non-MPI MultiNest libraries will be built.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/kevin/MultiNest/build
```

Any guidance on how to fix this?

Comment: make sure the `-devel` package are installed (e.g. you not only need `mpirun` but `mpicc` as well. you might also have to direct cmake to use the MPI wrappers instead of the compilers (`mpicc` instead of `gcc`, `mpifort` instead of `gfortran`, ...)

Comment: That did help, thanks. Cmake appeared to finish properly after I installed the -devel package. Now, the 'make' process has an error, which I will put in another post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When I installed 'libopenmpi-dev', the cmake process seemed to finish properly.